# Given this string input how could I make this given output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s = """
ID# VALUE_1 VALUE_2
  1      0.1          300
  2   0.2             400 (11 - this text is part of C in row 2 but needs to be ignored / removed)
  3          0.9          600"""
```

I am wanting to convert the above string into the formatted dictionary below. The spacing and extra text is like that on purpose. The spacing & noted text should be removed / stripped.

```
print(my_dict)
{'1': {'VALUE_1': '0.1', 'VALUE_2': '300'}, '2': {'VALUE_1': '0.2', 'VALUE_2': '400'}, '3': {'VALUE_1': '0.9', 'VALUE_2': '600'}}
```

What I've tried so far:

```
s = """
ID# VALUE_1 VALUE_2
  1      0.1          300
  2   0.2             400 (11 - this text is part of C in row 2 but needs to be ignored / removed)
  3          0.9          600"""

#Get the columns and assign them to a variable.
columns = s.lstrip().splitlines()[0] #Print the first line of the string

dct = {}

rows = s.lstrip().splitlines()

for data in rows[1:]:
    row = data.split()
    dct[row[0]] = dict(zip(columns[1:], row[1:]))

print(dct)
```

This ends up outputting an ugly unformatted looking dictionary :

```
{'1': {'D': '0.1', '#': '300'}, '2': {'D': '0.2', '#': '400', ' ': 'in', 'V': 'row', 'A': '2', 'L': 'but', 'U': 'needs', 'E': 'to', '_': 'be', '1': 'C', '2': 'ignored'}, '3': {'D': '0.9', '#': '600'}}
```

I've been unable to incorporate a way to successfully strip out the spaces and extra chunk of data on row2 with my current loop process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small bug in your code.

```
columns = s.lstrip().splitlines()[0]
```

does not give a list. Use:

```
columns = s.lstrip().splitlines()[0].split()
```

After making this modification, your code should run fine.

Moreover, improvising on it, you shouldn't use columns at all. Just replace it with rows[0].

Comment: And they could just use `rows[0]`; move the `columns` assignment a few lines lower and avoid stripping and splitting twice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you please clarify?

Comment: @IanSmith: Look at the work done for `rows` and for `columns`. You can use `columns = rows[0].split()` instead, avoiding stripping and splitting the larger `s` string.

Comment: Yes, @MartijnPieters is right. You see, columns is just rows[0] so why keep it twice?

Comment: @MartijnPieters 

Okay, so, like this?

https://hastebin.com/moripicawo.ini

Comment: @IanSmith: exactly like that.

Answer (score 2):

A `regex` solution, seems more *neat* to me:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([{i[0]:{'VALUE_1': i[1], 'VALUE_2': i[2]}}
...     for i in re.findall(r'^\s*(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)', s, re.M)])
[{'1': {'VALUE_1': '0.1', 'VALUE_2': '300'}},
 {'2': {'VALUE_1': '0.2', 'VALUE_2': '400'}},
 {'3': {'VALUE_1': '0.9', 'VALUE_2': '600'}}]
```

Check how does the `regex` works [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/JSwt6q/1/)

Comment: That's awesome! I was learning some regex the other night to see if it was a viable option. Did you rattle this off by memory or do you have a tool that helps you?

Comment: regex101.com is a great tool! check my update. Cheers @IanSmith